# How do you dynamically change react-navigation header style based on AsynStorage value?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an app that use react-navigation, and I have theme system in place, if the user chooses a specific color, it changes all the screens backgrounds to the selected color.
I'd like to do the same with react-navigation, so for example if person selects green color, the react-navigation header backgroundcolor would be green as well.

This is my themeProvider:

```
const STORAGE_KEY = 'THEME_ID';
const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [themeID, setThemeID] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const storedThemeID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
      if (storedThemeID) setThemeID(storedThemeID);
      else setThemeID(THEMES[1].key);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeID, setThemeID }}>
      {!!themeID ? children : null}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function withTheme(Component) {
  return props => {
    const { themeID, setThemeID } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const getTheme = themeID => THEMES.find(theme => theme.key === themeID);
    const setTheme = themeID => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, themeID);
      setThemeID(themeID);
    };

    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        themes={THEMES}
        theme={getTheme(themeID)}
        setTheme={setTheme}
      />

    );
  };
}
```

Screen example that already uses the theming

```
ArchivedScreen = ({ theme, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[style.container, { backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor }]}>
                    <Button title="Open drawer" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />

    </View>
  );
};



const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default withTheme(ArchivedScreen);
```

My question really is, how do I go about this?

This is my drawerNavigator:

```
  const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    Home: HomeStack,
    Tasks: {
      screen: TasksStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Task manager - -'
      }
    },
    Completed: {
      screen: CompletedStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Completed -'
      }
    },
    Archived: {
      screen: ArchivedStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Archived -',
      },

    },
    Calendar: CalendarStack,
    Notifications: NotificationStack,
    Settings: SettingsStack,
    Account: AccountStack,
  }); 


  HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    },
  }

  CompletedScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Completed tasks',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  TaskScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Tasks',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  ArchivedScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Archived tasks',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  AccountScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Account',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  CalendarScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Calendar',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  NotificationScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Notifications',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }

  SettingsScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Settings',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
    }
  }


export default drawerNavigator;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use backgroundColor as the selected theme to use as header background color.

I've tried to wrap navigator to use the withTheme hook and then export as `export default withTheme(drawerNavigator);` however that returns that it cannot find variable theme and turns into loop when loading the app?

Can anybody enlighten me how to go about this? I'm fairly new to react-navigation.

Comment: that would be helpful If you could put a runnable example of your code somewhere (either snack or git)